# SAS Proc UCM output breakpoints

Tags: sas, breakpoints

I have a timeseries dataset in SAS and I am running this data through the UCM procedure to identify signficiant structural breakpoints in the timeseries (changes in the expected mean).
My code is as follows:

```
 proc ucm data=temp;
by source;
   id date interval=month;
   model baseload;
   irregular;
   level checkbreak;
run;
```

The level checkbreak statement above is printed in the SAS output window in the section labeled 'outlier summary', but I need the output in a dataset.  The 'outest' statement only works for the 'estimate' statement and not the level statement in proc UCM.  Does anyone know know if it is possible to write this section out to a dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `OutlierSummary` table using SAS's ODS system.

Read about it here:
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/60372/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_ucm_sect034.htm